# Installing ZPsycopgDA on Zope

Tags: database, postgresql, zope

So, I'm trying to install ZPsycopgDA on Zope, but it keeps giving me the following error on the log file:

```
2022-02-13T02:11:01 ERROR Application Couldn't install ZPsycopgDA
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/rubens/zope/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/OFS/Application.py", line 660, in install_product
    global_dict, global_dict, silly)
  
File "/home/rubens/zope/instance/Products/ZPsycopgDA/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import DA
  
File "/home/rubens/zope/instance/Products/ZPsycopgDA/DA.py", line 21, in <module>
    import db
  
File "/home/rubens/zope/instance/Products/ZPsycopgDA/db.py", line 18, in <module>
    from Shared.DC.ZRDB.TM import TM

ImportError: No module named ZRDB.TM
```

I added the Zope lib directory to PYTHONPATH (/home/rubens/zope/lib64) as instructed, but still gives me this error. Any clues? I'm using Zope2==2.13.30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Had to install Products.ZSQLMethods (`pip install Products.ZSQLMethods==2.13.4`). I've installed this version because of Zope2==2.13.30 compatibility.